# Combinatorial approach to an inequality.

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that $$\left(\frac{2^{10}}{11}\right)^{11} \gt \binom{10}{1}^2\binom{10}{2}^2\binom{10}{3}^2\binom{10}{4}^2\binom{10}{5} $$

I am practicing for an upcoming exam, and this question got me stuck. The $2^{10}$ and the binomial coefficients really beg for a combinatorial approach here, but I can't think of a good way.

I came up with an algebraic approach though, which I am going to post as an answer. I am looking for a **combinatorial method** right now.

Note: I am tagging this as combinatorics because that is what I am looking for, but you can answer if it is something significantly different from my algebra approach.

Comment: Do you mean for the left hand side to appear as a fraction or as $2^{10}$ choose $11$. I assume the latter.

Comment: @JonnyLomond no it is a fraction. read my answer.

Answer (score 3):

My first observation was that the right hand side is $$\prod_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}$$ and the left hand side is $$\left(\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{10} \binom{10}{i}}{11}\right)^{11}$$

Applying the $A.M \gt G.M$ inequality,

$${a_0+a_1 + a_2+a_3+\ldots +a_{10}\over 11} \geqslant \sqrt[11]{a_0a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_{10}}$$

yields the desired result immediately, inequality holding since all $a_i$'s are not equal.

Comment: Careful. your "$>$" is because the $a_i$'s are different.

Comment: @vonbrand i know that. it is well known, so i didn't bother mentioning. i'll edit it then.